# resize canvas in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, html5-canvas, nuxt.js, responsive

Me again, with the blob. I am struggling to get my canvas element to resize and be mobile responsive like the rest of my layout in VueJS. Im using NuxtJS.

Below is my VueJS file (I call the resize() method in methods to trigger a window resize):

```
<template id="breath">
  <div id="page__home">
    <v-row dense>
      <v-col cols="12" align="center" justify="center">
        <h1 class="card__header">
          <v-icon large color="black">
            mdi-comment-question-outline
          </v-icon>
          Mindful Breathing
        </h1>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="450"></canvas>
        <h1 class="instructions">{{ breathText[0] }}</h1>
        <v-container fluid class="container">
          <v-row align="center" justify="center">
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn fab medium color="secondary">
              <v-icon color="black">
                mdi-volume-high
              </v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn fab x-large color="primary" @click="start">
              <v-icon large color="white">
                mdi-play
              </v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn fab medium color="secondary">
              <v-icon color="black">
                mdi-tune-vertical
              </v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Blob from "../assets/content/Blob_Point"
import { Point } from "../assets/content/Blob_Point"
let oldMousePoint = { x: 0, y: 0 }
let blob = new Blob()
let hover = false
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      canvas: null,
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      isDrawing: false,
      rectWidth: 200,
      dir: 0.25,
      radius: 200,
      ticker: undefined,
      timer: undefined,
      timerState: "stopped",
      displaySec: 10,
      breathText: ["Inhale", "Hold", "Exhale", "Hold"],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
    this.canvas = canvas.getContext("2d")
    canvas.setAttribute("touch-action", "none")
    blob = new Blob(this.color, this.canvas)
    blob.color = "#8CE5EA"
    blob.canvas = canvas
    blob.init()
    blob.render()
    blob.f_varySize()
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener("pointermove", this.mouseMove)
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.mouseMove)
  },
  methods: {
    start() {
      if (this.timerState !== "running") {
        this.tick()
        this.timerState = "running"
      } else {
        window.clearInterval(this.timer)
        this.timerState = "stopped"
      }
    },
    // ------ Text Change methods + Timer ---------//
    tick() {
      this.timer = window.setInterval(() => {
        this.textChange()
      }, 500)
    },
    textChange() {
      const first = this.breathText.shift()
      this.breathText = this.breathText.concat(first)
    },
    // ------------------------------------------//
    // ------ Window Resize (Not functioning)---//
    resize() {
      document.getElementById("canvas").width = window.innerWidth
      document.getElementById("canvas").height = window.innerHeight
    },
    //-------//
    // -------- spring/wave animation on mouseOver of blob ----//
    mouseMove(e) {
      let pos = blob.center
      let diff = { x: e.clientX - pos.x, y: e.clientY - pos.y }
      let dist = Math.sqrt(diff.x * diff.x + diff.y * diff.y)
      let angle = null
      blob.mousePos = {
        x: pos.x - e.clientX,
        y: pos.y - e.clientY,
      }
      if (dist < blob.radius && hover === false) {
        let vector = {
          x: e.clientX - pos.x,
          y: e.clientY - pos.y,
        }
        angle = Math.atan2(vector.y, vector.x)
        hover = true
        // blob.color = '#77FF00';
      } else if (dist > blob.radius && hover === true) {
        let vector = {
          x: e.clientX - pos.x,
          y: e.clientY - pos.y,
        }

        angle = Math.atan2(vector.y, vector.x)
        hover = false
        blob.color = null
      }
      if (typeof angle == "number") {
        let nearestPoint = null
        let distanceFromPoint = 100
        blob.points.forEach((point) => {
          if (Math.abs(angle - point.azimuth) < distanceFromPoint) {
            // console.log(point.azimuth, angle, distanceFromPoint);
            nearestPoint = point
            distanceFromPoint = Math.abs(angle - point.azimuth)
          }
        })
        if (nearestPoint) {
          let strength = {
            x: oldMousePoint.x - e.clientX,
            y: oldMousePoint.y - e.clientY,
          }
          strength =
            Math.sqrt(strength.x * strength.x + strength.y * strength.y) * 1
          if (strength > 100) strength = 100
          nearestPoint.acceleration = (strength / 100) * (hover ? -1 : 1)
        }
      }
      oldMousePoint.x = e.clientX
      oldMousePoint.y = e.clientY
    },
    // ----- //
    // ------ Blob initialisation ------//
    init() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.numPoints; i++) {
        let point = new Point(this.divisional * (i + 1), this)
        point.acceleration = -1 + Math.random() * 2
        this.push(point)
      }
    },
    //---------//
    // ------ changing blob radius (Not working) ----//
    f_varySize() {
      console.log("testing")
      this.ticker = setInterval(() => {
        /*if (this.radius > 200) {
          this.dir = -0.25
          //console.log(g_radius);
        }
        if (this.radius < 200) {
          this.dir = 0.25
          //console.log(g_radius);
        } */
        this.radius += this.dir
      }, 20)
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  z-index: -1;
}
.instructions {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 100;
}
</style>
```

Should I be doing this outside of the script tags? Is there another method in VueJS that I am not using to acheive this? I tried setting

```
      document.getElementById("canvas").width = window.innerWidth
      document.getElementById("canvas").height = window.innerHeight
```

to

```
      document.getElementById("canvas").width = this.window.innerWidth
      document.getElementById("canvas").height = this.window.innerHeight
```

But it doesnt seem to have any effect.

Here is a screenshot of the desktop view, and the mobile view

[Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPm9Q.png)

[Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAVM6.png)

Thanks to everyone who has been replying to my questions so far, you have been a massive help! I am new to development so its a rocky road :D

Answer (score 1):

if you are using vuetify
then [breakpoints](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/breakpoints/) can help you to set dynamic height width based on screen

```js
  new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      computed :{
        getWidth() {
          if(this.$vuetify.breakpoint.mobile){
              return 200
          } else {
              return 300
          }
          
        },
        getHeight() {
          if(this.$vuetify.breakpoint.mobile){
              return 200
          } else {
              return 300
          }
        }
      }
    })
```

```css
canvas{
  border : 1px solid
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-container>
          <canvas id="canvas" :width="getWidth" :height="getHeight"></canvas>
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to work for me, even after reducing the width and height to 75 within the getHeight and getWidth functions. Still the same result when I check the mobile view on chrome dev tools

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix just using CSS by setting the width to 100% and the height to auto

```
#canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
```